# Error when exporting SQL database from Azure to local

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, ssms, database-backups

I am trying to export a SQL database in Azure to my local machine using SSMS in order to create a local back up. I used 'Export Data Tier Application' for creating back up. But I am getting the error given below.

[image: Name of the database is what is hidden]

How can I get rid of this?

Comment: Hi StarLord, you must use the Azure SQL database server admin account to do the Export Data Tier Application. Please see my answer. If the answer is helpful for you, please mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: @ Leon Yue Did it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just from the error message, you don't have permission to alter/access the database.

If you want to do the Export Data Tier Application to create the backup bacpac file, you must using the Azure SQL database server admin account, or you don't have the enough permission.

Please try to using the Azure SQL database server admin account to do the operation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are right. I did it with a user having admin privileges and that worked.